# Who plays Jermaine Andrews in Grand Theft Auto IV?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

In Grand Theft Auto IV, [Jermaine Andrews](http://gta.wikia.com/Jermaine_Andrews)’ voice sounds to me like [Tracy Morgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracy_Morgan). But I can’t find any credits stating who played him.

Anyone know of a source to confirm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [GTA wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/Characters_by_Surname_%28Number-B%29):

> Voiced by: None Applicable

I also did a Google search of [Jermaine Andrews Tracy Morgan](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=Get&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=Jermaine+Andrews+Tracy+Morgan&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) and nothing relevant appeared

Comment: Jermaine Andrews isn't in the list on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Grand_Theft_Auto_voice_actors), [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0802999/fullcredits) or somewhere else listing the credits.

Answer (score 4):

There has been some [similar](http://uk.gamespot.com/xbox360/action/grandtheftauto4/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-42523338&pid=933037) [speculation](http://www.gtaforums.com/index.php?showtopic=325537) elsewhere online, but no confirmations that I can find.

There they refer to the character as “Playboy X”, which is not something I recommend Googling at work.

Comment: "...which is not something I recommend Googling at work." Schmuuuck bait

Answer (score -3):

The Guru, The same guy that voiced 8 Ball in GTA 3. I have no idea why nobody has not figured that out.

Comment: Do you have a source for this claim?